# Does additivity of (equivariant) cohomology hold at the algebra level?

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

The additivity property of many (co)homology theories is that if $X = \bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i$ then $H^*(X) = \bigoplus_{i\in I} H^*(X_i)$. This is usually either an axiom of the theory, can be proven directly, or follows from something like Mayer-Vietoris.

In all instances that I have seen, the above "equality" holds at the level of groups. The cup product makes $H^*(X)$ into a ring, and in some cases we may additionally put an $H^*(pt)$-module structure on $H^*(X)$ which is compatible with the cup product to turn $H^*(X)$ into an $H^*(pt)$-algebra (In particular, I am thinking of equivariant cohomology $H_G^*(X)$).

> If $H^*(X)$ is an $H^*(pt)$-algebra, is it still true that $H^*(X) = \bigoplus_{i\in I} H^*(X_i)$ on the level of algebras?

This would be nice, since it then seems to me that the product structures on each $X_i$ do not interact. Namely, if $\alpha \in H^*(X_i)$ and $\beta \in  H^*(X_j)$ for $i\neq j$ then $\alpha \beta =0$. Is this true?